# offensive IP Address

Tags: php, javascript, html, .htaccess

I got two suspicious visitors to my website and when I googled their IP addresses they showed up in one of the offensive IP databases. 
Is there a way to prevent any offensive IP address from accessing my website?
 Thanks

Comment: Do you really think that they don't know what proxy is?

Comment: @zerkms Sure they do. But does this mean nothing can be done to even minimize their offensiveness at least?

Comment: ban by IP will not protect you at all. The guys, that **can** hack you know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent an IP from accessing your site, put this in the top of your document:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '12.34.56.78')
    die('You have been banned.');
```

Instead if `die()` you can also use `exit` to stop the script, 
or `header('Location: http://www.google.com')` to send them to google.

Because there's a good chance they will resort to proxies, it might be better to link this to a database where you can insert all the IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

holds the visitors IP-address. You could check that against a list of IP-addresses you'd want to prevent from visiting.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

You can ban visitors by IP in PHP by using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] but if you're using Apache server I suggest HTACEESS way.

Use this pattern in your root folder .htaccess file

```
order allow,deny
deny from 123.45.6.7
deny from 012.34.5.
allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess file to block and IP address. However, as zerkms said, if they really want to get to your site they'll just use a proxy.

http://www.clockwatchers.com/htaccess_block.html